# using unix to remove carriage returns embedded within xml text

Tags: python, xml, unix

I have an xml file that i'm trying to process using python

I am getting errors  as occassionally some of the text within the xml strings have forced carriage returns within them

How do I remove these carriage returns in unix within the xml text without removing all of them because that would mean joining all the xml records together

Example of a xml script that I can parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz"><message attribute= 'hello world, i am not going to add a cariage return right now'></message></script>
```

Example of a xml script that I can't parse due to carriage returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz">
<message attribute= 'hello world, i am going to add a cariage return
right now
even though
i do not have to'></message></script>
```

My final output after parsing is going to look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz"><message attribute = 'hello world, i am not going to add a cariage return right now'></message></script>
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz"><message attribute= 'hello world, i am going to add a cariage return right now even though i do not have to'></message></script>
```

What I dont want, is to remove ALL carriage returns because my final output would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz"><message attribute= 'hello world, i am not going to add a cariage return right now'></message></script><?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz"><message attribute = 'hello world, i am going to add a cariage return right now even though i do not have to'></message></script>
```

Comment: Remove newlines with `tr -d '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all the example is not a valid xml. It could be either this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz">
<message attribute = 'hello world, i am going to add a cariage return
right now
even though
i do not have to'/></script>
```

or this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz">
<message>hello world, i am going to add a cariage return
right now
even though
i do not have to</message></script>
```

And I also assume that you want to remove `\n` not carriage returns.

Try this function:

```
import re
from lxml import etree

def removeEndl(xml):
   root = etree.XML(xml)

   for element in root.xpath('//*'):
      if element.text is not None:
         element.text = re.sub(r'\r?\n', '', element.text)
      for key, value in element.attrib.iteritems():
         element.attrib[key] = re.sub(r'\r?\n', '', value)

   return etree.tostring(root)
```

Comment: i want to remove \n but when i display the xml data in notepad++, the \n isn't showing as \n, it's showing as CRLF

Comment: When you open a file with python CRLF is converted to LF.  Anyway I edited the code to use regular expression which removes CRLF or LF.

Comment: "When you open a file with python CRLF is converted to LF." False. This only happens if you specify universal newline mode like @sebastian mentions in his answer.

Comment: According to [PEP 278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278) it is enabled by default. Basing on my own experience I can also say that it is enabled by default, but I work on machine with Windows. Is it different on Linux/MAC?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably also use python's support for [universal new lines](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines), when opening your xml file. This would make python replace any `\r\n` and `\r` by `\n`.

To use it, simply add a `U` to the [file open mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET
with open('my.xml', 'rU') as myxml:
    ET.parse(myxml)
```